# detecting usb devices android

Tags: android, android-intent

I am trying to make a toast pop up in my android app when a usb device is attached and detached..
the short - Its not working..  can someone please tell me what i am missing?  trying to connect a samsung hard keyboard to a samasung tablet and have my app detect it on attach or detach

my activity

```
    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.HashMap;

    import com.eliddell.R;
    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.app.PendingIntent;
    import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
    import android.content.Context;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.content.IntentFilter;
    import android.content.res.Configuration;
    import android.hardware.usb.UsbAccessory;
    import android.hardware.usb.UsbDevice;
    import android.hardware.usb.UsbManager;
    import android.location.GpsStatus.Listener;
    import android.mtp.MtpDevice;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.util.Log;
    import android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager;
    import android.widget.Toast;

    public class UiModeTestActivity extends Activity {
        /** Called when the activity is first created. */
        //UsbAccessory accessory = (UsbAccessory) intent.getParcelableExtra(UsbManager.EXTRA_ACCESSORY);

        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.main);
            String str = (String) getLastNonConfigurationInstance();

            IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter("android.hardware.usb.action.USB_ACCESSORY_ATTACHED");
registerReceiver(mUsbReceiver, filter);

        }


       private static final String ACTION_USB_PERMISSION ="com.android.example.USB_PERMISSION";
       private final BroadcastReceiver mUsbReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {

            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "received", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                String action = intent.getAction();
                if (UsbManager.ACTION_USB_ACCESSORY_DETACHED.equals(action)) {
                    UsbAccessory accessory = (UsbAccessory)intent.getParcelableExtra(UsbManager.EXTRA_ACCESSORY);
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "attached", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                if (UsbManager.ACTION_USB_ACCESSORY_ATTACHED.equals(action)) {
                    UsbAccessory accessory = (UsbAccessory)intent.getParcelableExtra(UsbManager.EXTRA_ACCESSORY);
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "detached", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        };

    };
```

my manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="12" />

<application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"

    >
    <uses-library android:name="com.android.future.usb.accessory" /> 
    <activity
        android:name=".UiModeTestActivity"
        android:configChanges="keyboard|uiMode|orientation"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
        <meta-data android:name="android.hardware.usb.action.USB_ACCESSORY_ATTACHED"
            android:resource="@xml/accessory_filter" />
    </activity>

</application>
```

Comment: Did you get some solution you can share?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit2:

> trying to connect a samsung hard keyboard to a samsung tablet

If I am not mistaken: Problem is that a keyboard is not an USB Acessory and should therefore not trigger the USB_ACCESSORY_ATTACHED part.

forget the part below :)

---

try replacing

```
 UsbManager mUsbManager = (UsbManager) getSystemService(Context.USB_SERVICE);
//final String ACTION_USB_PERMISSION ="com.android.example.USB_PERMISSION";

PendingIntent mPermissionIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, new Intent(ACTION_USB_PERMISSION), 0);
IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(ACTION_USB_PERMISSION);
registerReceiver(mUsbReceiver, filter);
```

with

```
IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter("android.hardware.usb.action.USB_ACCESSORY_ATTACHED");
registerReceiver(mUsbReceiver, filter);
```

and remove

```
<action android:name="android.hardware.usb.action.USB_ACCESSORY_ATTACHED" />
```

from your AndroidManifest.xml

You are confusing permissions with broadcast intents.

Edit: Uhm likely this is completely wrong: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/usb/accessory.html does what you do.

Comment: See "new" answer on top. Accessories are somewhat special and I guess your keyboard is no accessory (it would need to have batteries / power itself) and you get nothing therefore.